# HTML Button in Form and in DIV is leading to wrong direction

Tags: java, html

I wrote the following code:

```
out.println("<form action=\"PageA\" method=\"post\">");
// Table with input fields
out.println("<div id='split'>");    
out.println("<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Go\" /> </form>");
out.println("<a href=\"Page B\"><button>Back</button></a>");
out.println("</div>");
```

and now I wanted to format the 2 buttons right next to each other not one below the other one. So all I done: I created the div and in css said display flex.

But doing it like this, the buttons are next to each other, but as soon as I press the Back-Button I get redirected to PageA instead of PageB.

If I change the code to this:

```
out.println("<form action=\"PageA\" method=\"post\">"); 
// Table with input fields
out.println("<div id='split'>");
out.println("<input type=\"submit\" id='bill_one1_create' value=\"Go\" /> </form>");
out.println("</div>");
out.println("<a href=\"Page B\"><button>Back</button></a>");
```

The Back button works as intended, but the buttons are not next to each other because the back-button is not in the div. What is the solution to this, to achieve both things?

I am using a Servlet so thats why i am using "out.println..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I get redirected to PageA instead of PageB.

Because you're mixing up the HTML elements here:

```
<a href="Page B"><button>Back</button></a>
```

When you click on "Back", are you pressing a button or clicking a link?  How can you unambiguously determine the difference?  According to the behavior described, you're pressing the button and therefore submitting the form.

Don't put a `<button>` inside of an `<a>` (nor the other way around).  It's one or the other.  If you want this element to be a link, just make it a link:

```
<a href="Page B">Back</a>
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep the button shape?

Comment: @codingkappa: Yes, you can use CSS to style your elements however you like.  Alternatively, you could use a `<button type="button">` instead of an `<a>` and use JavaScript to navigate the user in the click handler for that button.  Personally I think the `<a>` is cleaner functionality if the overall goal is just navigating to a new resource.

Comment: even if I use a button and Javscript I still get redirected to the wrong page..

Comment: @codingkappa: Well, the primary suggestion is to not use a `<button>` but instead use an `<a>`, since the behavior you're looking for is exactly what an `<a>` is for.  If you really want to use a `<button>`, what is your updated code?

Comment: I found no way to make a <a> looking a standard button... If there is a option, I would gladly use that.

Comment: I added this function `function red() {return false; window.location.href='http://localhost:8080/folder/page';}` and changed the button to this: `out.println("<button onclick='return red();'id='cancelbtn'>Back</button></a>");`

Comment: @codingkappa: In that example you're missing the `type="button"` attribute.  The default `type` for a button is `submit`, which submits your form.

Answer (score 0):

Hello NEOPHYLE I see what you are saying. try this see

```
out.println("<div id='split'>");    
out.println("<div><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Go\" /> </form></div>");
out.println("<div><a href=\"Page B\"><button>Back</button></a></div>");
out.println("</div>");
```

then you go to the CSS file by calling the split ID and doing a flex display now playing with the margin and padding.
let me know if it's good.